# `git rebase -i`, several normal commits are missing from the interactive list

Tags: git

Environment: git version 2.17.1 on macOS 10.14.2

You can clone the repository for testing:

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/arzyu/9c4a50257bd2be18ed1e9774b7600070 rebase-demo
```

git log:

```
* 32b845d (origin/b2, b2) C7
| * be5dd19 (origin/b1, b1) C6
|/
| * 166caa4 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) C5
| * 27bb508 C4
| * 63aed5a C3
|/
* 1ed4bc4 C2
* 8ff08b7 C1
```

case 1:

```
# on master
git rebase -i b1


# list 1
pick 63aed5a C3
```

case 2:

```
# on master
git rebase -i b2

# list 2
pick 63aed5a C3
pick 27bb508 C4
pick 166caa4 C5
```

**Why are `C4` and `C5` not shown on list 1?**

Comment: Are C4 and C5 merges?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, they are normal commits.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue... I've created a small repo with the same tree structure, run `git rebase -i b1` on master, and I see commits C3, C4, and C5.

Comment: Did you use my gist repo? You can clone it for testing.

Comment: No I used my own which used the same tree structure as yours. (Assuming they’re all normal commits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: cloning the repository proves the theory correct; see addendum below.

The problem here is that rebase has decided that the commits are redundant.  In particular, `git rebase` (with or without `-i`) will omit commits that have an upstream commit that is "patch-equivalent".

That is, suppose we have:

```
...--F--G--H2--J2--K   <-- upstream
         \
          H--I--J   <-- branch
```

Here, if we ask Git to rebase `branch` onto `upstream`, Git would normally copy commits `H`, then `I`, then `J` so that the new copies go after commit `K`:

```
                     H3--I2--J3   <-- branch
                    /
...--F--G--H2--J2--K   <-- upstream
         \
          H--I--J   [abandoned]
```

However, while Git is preparing the list of commit hash IDs to copy, it does something slightly tricky: for each commit `H`, `I`, and `J`, it checks to see if any of the upstream-only commits—here, `H2`, `J2`, and `K`—have the same `git patch-id` as commits `H`, `I`, or `J`:

```
git show <hash> | git patch-id
```

more or less (try this to see how it works, though it's not exactly user-friendly).

If, as I'm implying by the names `H2` and `J2`, some of the commits have an upstream that "does the same thing", the rebase process will *drop* those commits.  In this case, since `H` is already replicated by `H2` and `J` is already replicated by `J2`, the actual rebase will produce:

```
                     I2   <-- branch
                    /
...--F--G--H2--J2--K   <-- upstream
         \
          H--I--J   [abandoned]
```

This seems to be what you are observing.  It's a bit odd, though, as this means that commits `C4` and `C5` must both have the same patch ID—there's only one upstream commit on `b1`, namely `C6`.  They can only be eliminated if they both have the same patch ID *and* that's the same as `C6`'s patch ID.

(Apparently `C7`'s patch ID is different, so the rebase keeps all the commits.)

#### Addendum

```
$ git clone https://gist.github.com/arzyu/9c4a50257bd2be18ed1e9774b7600070 gri
$ git show master~3..master | git patch-id
c711e5dfe43107af9bcff6c00bed4211d3b60cf6 166caa401ede4f97841a2715a80b4d26c40c50b8
c711e5dfe43107af9bcff6c00bed4211d3b60cf6 27bb50839ee73bce4cbb97089306c5dfa04c4516
2ee54397f45e5f955fc7b5b6717544e526818ede 63aed5a10cf22e1dd1ba699dac9104f3605a3751
```

The hash IDs on the left are the patch IDs, while the hash IDs on the right are the commit IDs (for C3, C4, and C5 respectively).  For instance:

```
$ git show master~2
commit 63aed5a10cf22e1dd1ba699dac9104f3605a3751
Author: arzyu <arzyu@live.cn>
Date:   Mon Dec 17 17:17:01 2018 +0800

    C3

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 4b87763..a25c784 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 //
 //
+
+//
```

Two are the same as the hash ID of the tip of `b1`:

```
$ git show origin/b1 | git patch-id
c711e5dfe43107af9bcff6c00bed4211d3b60cf6 be5dd192f9bed20036491915766be61d66eec8aa
$ git show origin/b1
commit be5dd192f9bed20036491915766be61d66eec8aa (origin/b1)
Author: arzyu <arzyu@live.cn>
Date:   Mon Dec 17 17:19:09 2018 +0800

    C6

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 4b87763..b8e0885 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 //
 //
+//
```

Since all three commits have patch ID `c711e5dfe43107af9bcff6c00bed4211d3b60cf6`, `git rebase` omits the two that would otherwise be copied.

The patch ID of a commit is, as [the `git patch-ID` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html) says:

> nothing but a sum of SHA-1 of the file diffs associated
>    with a patch, with whitespace and line numbers ignored.

Since all three patches are just *add a line consisting of `//`*, they all have the same patch-ID, and Git assumes that it is doing the correct thing when it omits them for rebase.

Comment: Your can clone it: `git clone https://gist.github.com/arzyu/9c4a50257bd2be18ed1e9774b7600070 git-rebase-i-demo`

Comment: Aha, and cloning it shows that it is in fact the patch IDs.

Comment: Yes, you say it! Thank you for answering so clearly.

Comment: Another mystery solved and thoroughly explained by @torek. Kudos!